Fairseq Installation Fails: Missing version.txt Error During Build Pyhton 3.11 how to fix?
I am trying to install the fairseq library using pip in a Conda environment, but the installation fails with the following error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [19 lines of output]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/conda/envs/beyond_scale_div_coeff/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
        main()
      File "/opt/conda/envs/beyond_scale_div_coeff/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/opt/conda/envs/beyond_scale_div_coeff/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
        return hook(config_settings)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-nrzuksph/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 327, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
        return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-nrzuksph/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 297, in _get_build_requires
        self.run_setup()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-nrzuksph/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup
        exec(code, locals())
      File "<string>", line 27, in <module>
      File "<string>", line 18, in write_version_py
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fairseq/version.txt'
    [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


What I’ve Tried:

updating pip
pip install fairseq

Environment Details:
Python Version: 3.11
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
Pip Version: 23.1.2
Conda Environment: Yes

How can I successfully install fairseq without encountering this error? Is there a workaround or a specific setup process I need to follow?

https://pypi.org/project/fairseq/#history
The online pip version of fairseq hasn't been updated since 2022.
Use the local install commands they list on their readme
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq
cd fairseq
pip install --editable ./

git clone will download fairseq to your current folder. pip install ./ will install the package. If you use pip install --editable ./ then your need to make sure you don't delete the folder you downloaded, since that folder will be needed to import and run fairseq.

I had to run these commands to get the dependencies installed. The latest version of pip will raise an error since support for the * symbol was changed.
pip install pip==24.0
pip install hydra-core==1.0.7 omegaconf==2.0.6
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq
pip install --editable ./fairseq -v

